# How can I close process by normal operation using command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, automation, continuous-integration

I had some processs are running in remote server. Then, I would like to close process and replace newer.

Now, I have a problem how to close process automatically.

I know we can use command to kill process, but it's force. like `taskkill`, ....

I would to close it in normal flow, then if the process have confirm windows before close what can I do?

Comment: What do you really want to do? Kill a process with taskkill /F ? I don't get the problem?

Comment: I just want to know have any methods what can close process by external process, but it not force to kill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of options to end/kill processes. Probably, the easiest ones are:

Using powershell (with or without force parameter)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-6

taskkill (also with or without force parameter)

Using something like Autoit (ProcessClose() )

Running something on a remote machine : use PsExec

Comment: If I use taskkill, how to confirm yes or no when process close?

Comment: If you need some kind of dialog/window control, I would use Autoit. You can manipulate windows and so on. If you do Not want  the process to pop up any windows, then kill it with force parameter.

Comment: If I use PsExec, could I get same action with Autoit?

Comment: You could use Psexec with Autoit.

Comment: So, I need try how to use `ControlClick` of AutoIT to click confirmwindow in remote application by PsExec running.